# Cannot get entire web page after query

Tags: javascript, python, screen-scraping, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to scrape the historical NAVPS tables found on this page:
http://www.philequity.net/pefi_historicalnavps.php

All the code here are the contents of my minimal working script. So it starts with:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

After studying the web page using Chrome's Inspect Element, I find that the Form Data sent are the following:

```
form_data = {}
form_data['mutualFund'] = '1'
form_data['year'] = '1995'
form_data['dmonth'] = 'Month'
form_data['dday'] = 'Day'
form_data['dyear'] = 'Year'
```

So I continue building up the request:

```
url = "http://www.philequity.net/pefi_historicalnavps.php"
params = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
request = urllib2.Request(url, params)
```

I expect this to be the equivalent of clicking "Get NAVPS" after filling in the form:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Then I read it with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
print soup.prettify()
```

But alas! I only get the web page as though I didn't click "Get NAVPS" `:(` Am I missing something? Is the server sending the table in a separate stream? How do I get to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at the POST request in firebug, I see one more parameter that you aren't passing: "type" is "Year".  I don't know if this will get the data for you, there's any number of other reasons it might not serve you the data.

Comment: That does it. I missed it indeed. Thanks!